# apply using values of each line in a data.frame as parameters in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have 1 data.frame as follows, each line is a different Stock data :

```
Teste=data.frame(matrix(runif(25), nrow=5, ncol=5))
colnames(Teste) <- c("AVG_VOLUME","AVG_RETURN","VOL","PRICE","AVG_XX")

    AVG_VOLUME AVG_RETURN   VOL       PRICE      AVG_XX
 1  0.7028197  0.9264265    0.2169411 0.80897110 0.3047671
 2  0.7154557  0.3314615    0.4839466 0.63529520 0.5633933
 3  0.4038030  0.4347487    0.3441471 0.07028743 0.7704912  
 4  0.5392530  0.6414982    0.4482528 0.11087518 0.3512511
 5  0.8720084  0.9615865    0.8081017 0.45781973 0.0137508
```

What i want to do is to apply the function GBM from package sde (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sde/sde.pdf) using the cols AVG_RETURN, VOL, PRICE as arguments for all lines in the data.frame.
Something like this :

```
Result <- apply(Teste,1,function(x) {
    GBM(x[,"PRICE"],x[,"AVG_RETURN"],x[,"VOL"],1,252)
})
```

So i want the **Result** to be a data.frame that runs GBM for each Stock in the **Teste** data.frame.

How can i get this result ?

Comment: It is rather unclear why a separate geometric stochastic differential equatio could be solved for each line of data. The apply function is used to run functions one line or one column at a time. SDE's would normally be givent vector arguments. I think you need to find a statistics oriented site that can help with your homework problem.

Comment: I don't see this question as out of context, what if a have simulate future paths for all stocks in a portfolio to do whatever analysis i need. I have all data needed to run a Geometric Brownian Motion in a data.frame and i want to run it for each stock in a most efficient way possible. It is not a homework and its applicable on a day to day routine of a riskmanager

Comment: Your notion that you can "run a GBM" seems incredibly simplistic. `GBM()` would give a single vector on the basis of input. But the result would be different for each run and you would need thousands of runs for each stock to perform any sort of risk analysis. I believe you don't understand what the goal should be and I suggest you need to clarify the goal first. When the specific goal can be clarified you will be ready for coding advice.

Comment: It doesn't matter my objective or if i need to generage N number of simulations for each stock, it doesn't even matter the use of GBM, because the point of the question is not what i want to specifically accomplish, the point is much more generic. If you ignore the GBM and the rest, the question is simply : if i have a function that takes N number of parameters, and i have a data.frame with columns that have the variables that i want to input in this function, what is the most efficient way to go line by line, inputing the values on the columns as parameters and getting the result in each line

Comment: For learning sake, you might want to check out ?mapply

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the narrow question about why you are getting errors is that when the `apply` function passes values it is only as a vector rather than a dataframe, so removing hte commas in the arguments to `"["` will get you a result.

```
Result <- apply(Teste,1,function(x) {
    GBM(x[,"PRICE"],x[,"AVG_RETURN"],x[,"VOL"],1,252)
})
```

If you need it to be a dataframe where each stock would be a column, and the input datastructure has meaningful stock names,  then I suggest using:

```
dfRes <- setNames( data.frame(Result), rownames(Teste) )
```

I think the only way this could be meaningful in a risk analysis context is if many more simulation runs than these single instances are assembled in some higher level context.